# Show that for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, there exists a unique solution to $e^x= 2 - nx$

Tags: real-analysis, exponential-function

Basically I want to show, that for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$ there exists only one solution for each $n$ to $e^{x} = 2 - nx$. This seems somewhat obvious if you look at the graph of $e^x$ and $-nx$, since there is no way for any negative slope to cut through $e^x$ twice.

However, this is not a rigorous approach and I don't know at all how to start proving this. How would one prove this, or start proving this?

Comment: What are the variations of $f(x) = e^x - 2 + nx$ ?

Comment: Consider $f(x) = e^x  + nx - 2$. Show that it is strictly monotonically increasing (hint: consider $f'$). What are $f(-\infty)$ and $f(+\infty)$? What can you conclude from these? (Note: $f$ is continuous)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f(x)=e^x-2+nx$. Then $\lim_{x\to -\infty}f(x)=-\infty$ and $\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x)=+\infty$. By the intermediate value theorem, $f(c)=0$ at some point. $f'>0$, so this is a unique point.